# How do I set the font size of a field in a PDF form?

Tags: javascript, vba, pdf

I have a pdf form and Acrobat Pro installed on my machine. In MS Access I can write VBA code to open the form and fill out the fields.

How do I adjust the font size of a field (or other properties like color) using VBA?

```vb
Dim oAVDoc As Object, oPDDoc As Object
Dim oJso As Object, oFld As Object

Set oAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

oAVDoc.Open("C:\Temp\test.pdf", "")

Set oPDDoc = oAVDoc.GetPDDoc

Set oJso = oPDDoc.GetJSObject

Set oFld = oJso.getField("TestFieldName")

oFld.Value = "This is the new value." '<-- works fine

oFld.FontSize = 14 '<-- "Object doesn't support this property or method"
oFld.Color = "red" '<-- also does not work
```

There are probably javascript object properties for these, but I can't find any documentation.

Comment: Try `textSize` instead of FontSize (see also [documentation](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/html2015/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FField_properties.htm&rhsearch=getField&rhhlterm=getField&rhsyns=%20)

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I couldn't find that.

Comment: Well the textSize property works with no problem. But the textColor property is tricky. That documentation shows you how to do it in javascript, but not in VBA.

I tried assigning "red", "color.red", "#FF0000", 255, "255" nothing seems to work.

Comment: I agree, but my client wants one to be red to jump out.

Comment: I believe I found the answer anyway: oFld.textColor = Array("RGB", 255, 0, 0)

Comment: @Shrotter Thank you for the answer. I voted your comment up, but I don't know how to flag is as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
`oFld.textSize = 14`
instead of `FontSize` (see also [documentation](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/html2015/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FField_properties.htm&rhsearch=getField&rhhlterm=getField&rhsyns=%20))